# using variables from component in input tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, render

I have the code below:

```
import React from 'react'

const DogPound = () => {
    async function determineCats() { 
        var catcounter = 0;
        var cat_data = await getCats();
        var cat_1 = user_data['cat_1'];
        var cat_2 = user_data['cat_2'];
        var cat_3 = user_data['cat_3'];

        if(cat_1) {
            catcounter++; 
        }
        if(cat_2) {
            catcounter++; 
        }
        if(cat_3) {
            catcounter++; 
        }
        return(catcounter);
    }

    determineCats()
        .then(response => {
             console.log(response)
        });

    return (
        {Array.from({ length: catcounter }, (_unused, index) => index + 1).map(
            (catIndex) => {
                const catId = `cat_${catIndex}`
                return (
                    <div key={catId} className="cat-box">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="" /> //where placeholder is should be the variable
                    </div>
                )
            },
        )}
    )
}
```

As you can see, the point of the program is to create as many divs as there are catcounter values. The question I have is how can I inject a value for placeholder that is equivalent to the respective value of cat_ variables.

Desired outcome example:

First div will have a placeholder of cat_1
Second div will have a placeholder of cat_2
Third div will have a placeholder of cat_3

I tried simply hard coding the variables in but it does not render properly as the above code is comprised of Promises so it requires something extra.

Not sure what to do.

Comment: What does `cat_data`/`userData` look like?  It's an object with keys like `cat_1` etc.?  Are there any other keys that we need to ignore? Is the length of the keys array the same as `catcounter`?

Comment: @LindaPaiste it is an object, counter is just a number that increases based on how many nonempty entries there in an object

Comment: Ok so the complication is that we have multiple sets of properties on the same object.  Are you in control of how this user object is formatted on the backend/API?  Because I kind of hate this structure but we can work with it.  Are we assuming that all non-empty values come before all empty values?

Answer (score 0):

> I tried simply hard coding the variables in but it does not render properly as the above code is comprised of Promises so it requires something extra.

You need to make use of React `useState` and `useEffect` hooks.  You will trigger `getCats` from a `useEffect` hook.  When the value has been received, you update your state with it.

I am unsure about some of your requirements. Is `catcounter` just the number of cats in `cat_data`?  Can we loop through the keys instead of an array of numbers?

```js
const DogPound = () => {
  // an object where the keys are 'cat_1', 'cat_2', etc
  // and the values are strings - used as the placeholder
  const [catData, setCatData] = useState({});

  useEffect(
    () => {
      // need to define and call function separately
      // because the useEffect cannot return a Promise
      const loadData = async () => {
        const cat_data = await getCats();
        setCatData(cat_data);
      };
      loadData();
    },
    // empty dependency array means that it runs once
    // when the component is mounted
    []
  );

  // will be empty while it is loading, then populate
  // with inputs when ready
  return (
    <div>
      {Object.entries(catData).map(([catId, value]) => (
        <div key={catId} className="cat-box">
          <input type="text" placeholder={value} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const getCats = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(
      () =>
        resolve({
          cat_1: "Ted",
          cat_2: "Jasper",
          cat_3: "Whiskers"
        }),
      1000
    );
  });
};
```

Comment: This can definitely be improved but I think this is the general idea of what you want: https://codesandbox.io/s/add-additional-inputs-dh8v6?file=/src/App.tsx